# zoom out using javascript css

Tags: javascript, css, webkit

for zooming I am using 
el.style.zoom = 1.5;
el.style.WebkitTransform = 'scale(1.5)';

here e1 will be ,

I use webkit based browsers.

Now how do I zoom back to original size ? Confused bec document says for zoom out have to use less than 1, and how to scale back to original size in webkit ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use percentages.

For zoom in:

```
el.style.zoom = "150%";
```

For zoom to normal:

```
el.style.zoom = "100%";
```

This should work in webkit browsers.

Comment: Cool , It works. Any Idea how to zoom in a image on particular point ?
Main problem here is I cannot centre the image where I want to zoom.

Comment: @sat: Sure, use `zoom` (or a larger image) and absolutely position the image in a relatively positioned `<div />` that has its `overflow` set to `hidden` and then position the image inside it as needed.