# css / javascript page zoom

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have been trying to find a way to get the web browsers current web page zoom depending on the screen resolution that is currently in use. What would be the best method to get the page zoom as a number and then adjust the page accordingly using the following code,

Code Example,

```
zoom: 1.5;
-moz-transform: scale(1.5);
-webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
```

I will be adjusting using JS Script. Any examples of the best method to do this would be helpfull.

Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [zoom out using javascript css](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2028381/zoom-out-using-javascript-css)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using jQuery, jQuery Zoomooz.js ( http://janne.aukia.com/zoomooz/ ) handles this for you.